# Trying to understand simulation errors with Xilinx

Tags: vhdl, xilinx

I am getting some erros that I cant make sense and was hoping I could get some help.

```
ERROR: [VRFC 10-469] cannot update 'in' object shift_reg [C:/Users/Darren/Desktop/project_6_1_3/project_6_1_3.srcs/sources_1/new/1Bit_delay_register.vhd:25]
ERROR: [VRFC 10-925] indexed name is not a std_logic_vector [C:/Users/Darren/Desktop/project_6_1_3/project_6_1_3.srcs/sources_1/new/1Bit_delay_register.vhd:27]
ERROR: [VRFC 10-1504] unit simple_one_bit_serial_shift_register_behavior ignored due to previous errors [C:/Users/Darren/Desktop/project_6_1_3/project_6_1_3.srcs/sources_1/new/1Bit_delay_register.vhd:16]
INFO: [VRFC 10-240] VHDL file C:/Users/Darren/Desktop/project_6_1_3/project_6_1_3.srcs/sources_1/new/1Bit_delay_register.vhd ignored due to errors
```

I have tried altering the code to suit but nothing works ! this is the code:

```
    library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.std_logic_arith.all;
use ieee.std_logic_unsigned.all;

entity simple_one_bit_serial_shift_register is
   port(
      clk      : in  std_logic;
      reset      : in  std_logic;
      shift_in  : in  std_logic_vector(31 downto 0);
      shift_reg  : in std_logic_vector(1 downto 0);
      shift_out : out std_logic_vector(31 downto 0)
   );
end simple_one_bit_serial_shift_register;

architecture simple_one_bit_serial_shift_register_behavior of simple_one_bit_serial_shift_register is 
begin

--signal shift_reg : std_logic_vector(31 downto 0);
--signal shift_in : std_logic;
--signal shift_out : std_logic;
process (clk) 
    begin
    if rising_edge(clk) then
        shift_reg <= shift_reg(30 downto 0) & shift_in;
    end if;
    shift_out <= shift_reg(31);
end process;
end simple_one_bit_serial_shift_register_behavior
```

;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In line 25 the input `shift_reg` port is assigned, using `shift_reg <= ...`, but it is not legal to assign to an input port.

In line 27 there is reference to bit 31 in `shift_reg(31)`, but `shift_reg` only has index 1 and 0 in declaration with `shift_reg  : in std_logic_vector(1 downto 0);`.  And indexing a single bit like `(31)` has type `std_logic`, which does not match the `std_logic_vector` type of target `shift_out`.

Comment: Thanks for clearing it up, I have managed to fix the problem of line 25 by declaring the signal but the 2nd one is still confusing. I have tried chaing the bit declarations and ranges but its still giving me the same problem

Comment: Right, there is also a problem with the type, and I have added a sentence to the answer about this.